# Quartz calling triggerMisfired method twice for same event

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler clustered implementation with `org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered` set to `true`.

Occasionally some of the triggers(Weekly recurring event) are misfired twice.

```
public class XX implements TriggerListener {

   //This method is getting called twice for same quartz event.
   @Override
    public void triggerMisfired(Trigger trigger) {

}

}
```

Please help me understand how it is possible? And what could be the possible root cause?